# VueJS v-select submit

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou usando o `V-SELECT` para fazer um select estilo `Chosen`. Bom, ele funciona! Mas quando eu uso "ENTER" para inserir novos elementos, ele dá `SUBMIT` no form. Tem como eu dar submit apenas quando clicar no botão e não quando dar **ENTER** no `input`?

[Código Exemplo CODE PEN](https://codepen.io/JacksonJohnson28/pen/YrQENo)

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select</h1>
  <p>Try to add items in input using "ENTER"</p>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="submited()">
  <v-select multiselect :options="options"></v-select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: ["some", "thing", "another", "things"]
  },
  methods: {
    submited(){
      alert('submited!')
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse select não parece ter como parar o evento de submir no DOM. Assim tens de colocar uma `div` por exemplo à volta do componente para poder parar o event.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
 <div @keydown.prevent>
    <v-select multiple :options="options"></v-select>
 </div>
```

**Codepen: https://codepen.io/sergiocrisostomo/pen/dVRZmx?editors=1010**

Não conhecia esse componente. Eu uso muito [a biblioteca iview](https://www.iviewui.com/components/select-en).

Comment: Eita, curti essa `iview`

Comment: @RafaelAugusto eu também, por isso escolhi usar no trabalho :)

Comment: vou começar a usar tambem, eu estava utilizando o `Vuetify`

Comment: Legal @Sergio !! Obrigado pela ajuda e pela dica do iview :)